# Changing src of image dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image

im trying to work on a image color changing project. where you can changing the color per area of the picture.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div id="name">Title</div>

<div id="imageholder">
   <div class="holder"><img src="images/foldername/ar000.png" id="layer_a" /></div>
   <div class="holder"><img src="images/foldername/br000.png" id="layer_b" /></div>
   <div class="holder"><img src="images/foldername/cr000.png" id="layer_c" /></div>
   <div class="holder"><img src="images/foldername/dr000.png" id="layer_d" /></div>
   <div class="holder"><img src="images/foldername/empty.png" id="layer_map" usemap="#imgmap" /></div>
</div>

<map name="imgmap">
   <area shape="poly" id="c" class="map" coords="1,1,1,1,1" href="#" />
   <area shape="poly" id="d" class="map" coords="2,2,2,2,2" href="#" />
   <area shape="poly" id="a" class="map" coords="3,3,3,3,3" href="#" />
   <area shape="poly" id="a" class="map" coords="4,4,4,4,4" href="#" />
   <area shape="poly" id="b" class="map" coords="5,5,5,5,5" href="#" />
</map>

<div id="color">
   <img src="images/image1.jpg" id="r001" class="swatch"/></div>
   <img src="images/image2.jpg" id="r002"class="swatch"/></div>
   <img src="images/image3.jpg" id="r003" class="swatch"/></div>
   <img src="images/image4.jpg" id="r004"class="swatch"/></div>
   ......
</div>

<input name="currentpart" id="currentpart" type="hidden" value="" />
```

The image parts (layer_a to layer_d) will be layered on top of each other to create a single image. "layer_map" cointains a blank png image where the maps are drawn.

the user first clicks on one of the maps on the image form "imageholder" and then clicks on one of the image from "color" which in turn changes the image in "class="holder".

**Here is the jQuery codes**

```
// retrieves the image title //
var name = $("#name").text();
// on clicking the mapped areas //
('#imgmap area').click(function(){
    var idmap = $(this).attr('id');
// trying to put the selected area id into a hidden field //
    $("input[name='currentpart']").val(this.idmap);
});

// on choosing what color to change //
$('#color img').click(function(){
// trying to capture the stored id //        
   var mapcurrent = $("input[name='currentpart']").val();
// trying to create the id of the layer inside imageholder div//
   var imgid = "layer_"+ mapcurrent;
// geting the id of the clicked image in color div //
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
// replaces the image in the require layer //
   imgid.attr('src', "images/"+ name +"/"+ mapcurrent + this.id +".png");
```

lets say we click on map **"id=a"** and then click on a color **"id=r002"**. When we do this the img inside imageholder with  "id=layer_a" src will change to  **"images/Title/ar002.png"**

Thats what im trying to achieve but it dosent work :(

Comment: What is this: `var imgid = "layer_"+ mapcurrent;`, joining a string with an object? I don't think that works..

Comment: Thinks a lot for pointing out the problem.. :D iv figured out a way instead of `var imgid = "layer_"+ mapcurrent;` i replaced it with 'var imgid = $('#layer_'+ mapcurrent);' and it worked!!